# HttpClient keep-alive not working on ubuntu

Tags: mono

Client is sending keep-alive headers as is the server, but client is actually creating a new tcp connection for every request.  This is mono 3.2.3 built from source on ubuntu 13.10.

Test code:

https://gist.github.com/chrisochs/7113668

Ngrep session showing keep-alive headers but client making sequential requests with different originating ports:
https://gist.github.com/chrisochs/7113886

Am I doing something obviously wrong?